# Populating A combo box USING distinct values from a table

Tags: sql, asp-classic

i have this code for populating combo boxes for the page the admin staff, allowing them to search for courses that have been booked in accordance to their skill level, however seen as it is for my A2 computing i decided to populate the combo box with the values from the table, sadly, as expected, it shows reoccurences of the same value inputted on the table, so how do I adapt my current code for this(ref microsoft dev site) to essentially do the equivalent of a SELECT DISTINCT, yet stil populate the combo box. Thanks

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
    <BR>This is an HTML ListBox<BR>
    <SELECT NAME="ListBox" SIZE=1>
    <% Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") %>
    <% conn.Open "DSN=AdvWorks"  ' connect to the database %>
   <% Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT City FROM Customers") %>
   <% Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs %>
       <OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("City") %>"> <%= rs("City") %>
       <% rs.MoveNext %>
    <% Loop %>
    <% rs.Close %>
    <% conn.Close %>
   </SELECT>
   </BODY>
   </HTML>`
```

Comment: why aren't you using `<% Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers") %>`?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do a SELECT DISTINCT is to, well, do a SELECT DISTINCT.

(What's with the turning code off and on for every single line?)

```vbs
<p>Select city: <select name="listbox" size="1">
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "DSN=AdvWorks"  ' connect to the database
'- construct SQL query (your actual query could be much, much more 
'  complicated than this):
Dim sql : sql = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers"
Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)
Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs
   Response.Write "<option value=""" & rs("City") & """"
   '- you can put code here to test if this should be the selected option
   '  (if yes, you'd write out " selected=""selected""")
   Response.Write ">" & rs("City") & "</option>"
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
conn.Close    
%>
</select></p>
```